# Python Catch Calls that prompt the user for input

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

I have a python script that is using a package that on a call prompts the user for input (using GitPython and calls to fetch, push, and pull ask for username and password, I can't use ssh keys due to system structure so I am forced to use HTTP).

However, I have the values for the username and password in local variables from command line arguments to my script.  Is there a way to catch these calls and pipe in the correct values?  The below is pseudo code, but something along these lines

```
try:
    repo.push()
catch UserInputRequiredError as e:
    shell.send(username)
    shell.send(password)
```

Comment: I suspect this will depend on the API of the library you're using. If it's communicating with the user input directly without letting your code intervene, there may not be an easy solution. I suppose you could try messing around with replacing `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` to intercept the library's attempts at things, but it would be very awkward (you'd probably need extra threads and other nonsense).

Comment: Alright, I'll look into another workaround or deal with IT and get keys everywhere.  Thanks for that

Comment: "I have the values for the username and password [...] from command line arguments to my script" --- Depending on your situation, a password command-line argument could be a very bad idea.  On Unix variants, commands and their arguments are stored in the world-readable process table, revealing the password to anyone who looks (with `ps -elf` or `ps auxwww`) while the process is running.  I don't know if other operating systems could cause similar problems.

Comment: That's a really good catch. Thanks for the heads up @KevinJ.Chase